# Place holder in C#

Tags: c#

```
   using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace switch_calculator
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                double num1, num2;
                char opt;

                Console.WriteLine("Enter num1");
                num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Enter num2");
                num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

       Console.WriteLine("Select the operation you would like to perform" );
       Console.WriteLine("Press \n 'A' for Add \n 'S' for subtraction
\n 'D' for Division \n 'M' for multiplicatiion \n 'R' for Remainder");

                opt = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
                switch(opt)
                {
                    case 'A':

                        Console.WriteLine("your Add result  {0} + {1} is {2}", num1, num2, num1+num2);
                        break;
                }

                Console.ReadLine();

            }
        }
    }
```

1. Here it's my C# code , I'm very new to programming I was just
   wondering can I assign place holder value to other number like
   {0},{7} or {1},{3} instead of {0},{1} in the switch case statement
   case A ?? can someone pls explain the place holder concept here ?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? Those are just indexes of your parameters.

Comment: Why would you want to? What would the purpose be?

Comment: Thanks for the response I agree those are indexes, but can I assign start indexing those num1 and num2 variables to index values  {1}+{7} instead of {0}+{1} ???

Comment: @DrewKennedy  I just want to know about how these place holders can be used ? in every example coders using place holders values only {0} and {1} so I was just wondering can I store those local variables num1 and num2 into other index values like {2} or {7} or any other random index numbers

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

What does this error indicates ?

Comment: If C# 6 is available to your development environment then I would suggest using string interpolation. This way you can use them in whichever order you like https://www.dotnetperls.com/string-interpolation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the placeholders require a number that indexes from the first argument after the format string, zero-based.

So `Console.WriteLine("Hello, {0}!", "World")` will print `"Hello, World!"`, and `Console.WriteLine("Hello, {1}!", "ignored", "World")` will print the same.

You can't index into arguments that don't exist.

I guess you want to change for example the word "Add" for each operation, without having to repeat the entire format string.

You could do that by preparing a string with all the proper placeholders, and then assign them in the proper `case` block:

```
string format = "Your {0} result is {1} {2} {3} = {4}";

string operation = "";
string symbol = "";
double result = 0;

switch(opt)
{
    case 'A':
        operation = "Add";
        symbol = "+";
        result = num1 + num2;
        break;
    case 'S':
        operation = "Subtract";
        symbol = "-";
        result = num1 - num2;
        break;
    break;
    ...
}
```

Now you can print the whole line:

```
string format = "Your {0} result is {1} {2} {3} = {4}";

...

Console.WriteLine(format, operation, num1, symbol, num2, result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.WriteLine("your Add result  {0} + {1} is {2}", num1, num2, num1+num2);
```

Let me explain what everything means here:

```
Console.WriteLine(string text, params object[] obj);
```

This is the method without values.
As you can see, you give it a string to print and a list of parameters.

When you run this method, it will be filled with the following values:

```
text = "your Add result  {0} + {1} is {2}";
obj  = new object[3];
obj[0] = num1;
obj[1] = num2;
obj[2] = num1+num2;
```

Now what the formatter does is place the values of the objects that are returned by the `ToString()`-method at the given indexes.

Lets just assume that `num1` is `4` and `num2` is `5`.

```
"your Add result  {0} + {1} is {2}"
```

will be filled like this

```
"your Add result  4 + 5 is 9"
```

But if you change the indexes to lets say

```
"your Add result  {2} + {0} is {1}"
```

it will turn out like this

```
"your Add result  9 + 4 is 5"
```

If you give the `string` indexes that do not exist in the array (like e.g. `{7}`) the application will crash, stating that the requested index, in this case `7`, is `null`. This will be a `System.FormatException`.

It would be the same if you are trying to get the value of index `7` in an array with a size of `4` elements.

Comment: Awesome ! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, you can't provide a formatted specifier for a value that doesn't exist. For example:

```
Console.WriteLine("{1}", "test");
```

Would throw a `FormatException` because only one parameter is provided (arrays being 0-based).

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. A syntax sugar is to use `$"your Add result {num1} + {num2} is {num1+num2}`. And still you can't change the indexing of the placeholders. They always start from 0